# How do I get out of full-screen mode in MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

I am in full-screen mode in MobaXterm and can't seem to get out of it. I tried right-clicking and selecting "reset the terminal", but that didn't work.

I also tried Alt-Tab, `F8` and other escape sequences I use in other programs, but nothing obvious seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

Keyboard solution: `F11` toggles you in/out of full-screen mode ([see documentation](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html)).

Mouse solution: Move your cursor to the top of the screen and pause once it touches the edge of the screen. A toolbar will appear. Then click on "Fullscreen" to toggle out of that mode.

[image]

Comment: How do you put the Xsession window (when you have "constrainted to a single container window" turned on) in and out of full screen?